# Prolog existence_error from book example

Tags: prolog

I'm learning prolog from a book. When I enter the book's example in my file and try to run it I get existence error.

The example:

```
dog(fibo).
cat(felix).
animal(X) :- dog(X).
```

Then I try:

```
consult('test.pl').
animal(fibo).
```

I get:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,dog/0),animal/0)
```

I do not even understand the error message.

Update: Picture of the program and error attached.
[Program and error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U17vC.png)

**Update 2**: Installed `swi-prolog` and there is no problem. It seems the problem is related to `gprolog`.

Comment: That error seems to suggest there is a procedure `dog/0` in a clause for `animal/0`. Are you sure you wrote `animal(X) :- dog(X)` instead of `animal :- dog`?

Comment: @rajashekar yes.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error. It is working fine for me.

Comment: @rajashekar I'm using gprolog on ubuntu. Should I do anything except opening gprolog and importing the file?

Comment: Everything looks fine. I see nothing that could result in that error. Can you `trace/0`? Just type `trace.` and then enter `animal(fibo).` and keep pressing return key. Also check if `listing(animal)` is showing just your definition of animal.

Comment: `lisintg(animal)` is showing my definition. Following is the trace result.
`| ?- animal(fibo).
      1    1  Call: animal(fibo) ?
      2    2  Call: dog ?
      2    2  Exception: dog ?
      1    1  Exception: animal(fibo) ?
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,dog/0),animal/0)
{trace}`

Comment: In the second line of trace, call should have been to `dog(fibo)` instead of just `dog`. I'm not sure what is going on. Is your `gprolog` installation recent? Is `swi-prolog` available to install? I suggest trying it.

Comment: @rajashekar thanks, I installed swi-prolog and there is no problem.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, this interaction works fine on `gprolog` on a current Ubuntu system, where `gprolog` identifies itself as `GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)`, `Compiled Feb 23 2020, 20:14:50 with gcc`, `Copyright (C) 1999-2020`. So despite the same version number, this appears to be a much newer version.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie I installed `gprolog` using apt, should I download it from website?

Comment: @RamyarKhalili I also installed it via `apt`. `dpkg -l | grep gprolog` says it's version `1.4.5.0-3`. My system according to `lsb_release -a` is `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`.